# I need a code which should get Date from Excel as YYYY-MM-DD format using java

Tags: java, excel, selenium, date-format

I need a code which should get Date from Excel as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

It is displaying the date as 31-Dec-2050 which was originally saved in sheet as 2050-12-31 Format.

```
System.out.println("<" + sheet.getRow(i).getCell(24) + ">");
```

should get Date from Excel as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: you need to use date formatting APIs like SimpleDateFormat

Comment: [How to use the FORMAT Function with Dates (VBA)](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/format_date.php)

Comment: @SM That terrible date-time class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( 
    "31-Dec-2050" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uuuu" , Locale.US )
)
.toString()
```

## *java.time*

Your Question is unclear as you do not explain what library you might be using to read Excel files, nor do you explain what `sheet.getRow(i).getCell(24)` is doing. So I can only address how to parse a date string, and not give a potentially better, deeper answer.

If you are given the string `31-Dec-2050` you can parse that as a `LocalDate` in Java.  The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

Define a formatting pattern to match your textual input.

Pass a [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) to determine:

- The *human language* for translation of name of day, name of month, and such.
- The *cultural norms* deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Ex:

```
String input = "31-Dec-2050" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uuuu" , Locale.US ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/aSgHxf).

> ld.toString(): 2050-12-31

Answer (score 0):

Import:

```java
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
```

Then in your class:

```
String cv = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(24).getStringCellValue();
DateTimeFormatter dt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd");
System.out.println("<" + LocalDate.parse(cv).format(dt) + ">");
```

Comment: I am getting the following error "The method parse(String) in the type DateFormat is not applicable for the arguments (XSSFCell)" @aaa